# Expected 11 fields in line 14, saw 12. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have read about some answers on the similar problems, but it still doesn't work in my case.

```
df = pd.read_csv('auto-mpg.data', sep='\s+', header=None, names=col_names, engine='python')
```

this is the original code, and it shows

```
Expected 11 fields in line 14, saw 12. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.
```

and I check the data, the 14th line is:

```
14.0   8   455.0      225.0      3086.      10.0   70  1    "buick estate wagon (sw)"
```

what I think is it may because of the brackets results in this problem, so how should I do in this case? thanks

Comment: What shape should you data frame have? and is the 14th row any different. By the looks of things pandas is reading your csv and when trying to split the data in the 14th line, an anomaly in the data is causing that row to have an extra column. Im assuming. maybe edit the question to include the first 14 lines of the original CSV. Also a link to the answers you have checked would help

Comment: are you sure the delimeter is spaces and not fixed width? you might have to play around with sep or read in a different way.